# Why is the TensorFlow 2.x with @tf.function twice as fast as pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensorflow2.0

On small models or small datasets, **tf2 with @tf.function is twice as fast as pytorch**.

Why Pytorch is slower than Tensorflow on small datasets/models? Am I setting it wrong? Is there any way to speed up pytorch?

TF2 version

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
import numpy as np
import time
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
dims = 600
DATA_SIZE = 10000
batchsz = 100
epochs = 10
lr=1e-3
inputs = np.random.random([DATA_SIZE, dims]).astype(np.float32)
targets =np.random.random([DATA_SIZE, dims]).astype(np.float32)
tic_total=time.time()
model=keras.Sequential([layers.Dense(dims),
                        layers.ReLU(),
                        layers.Dense(dims),
                        layers.ReLU(),
                        layers.Dense(dims),
                        layers.ReLU(),
                        layers.Dense(dims),
                        layers.ReLU(),
                        layers.Dense(dims),
                        layers.ReLU(),
                        layers.Dense(dims)])


train_db = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((inputs,targets))  # [w*h,C]
train_db = train_db.shuffle(DATA_SIZE).batch(batchsz)
optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(lr)

@tf.function
def bp():
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(model(data[0]) - data[1]))
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

for epoch in range(epochs):
    tic_epoch=time.time()
    for step, data in enumerate(train_db):
        bp()
    toc_epoch = time.time()
    print('time per epoch:', toc_epoch - tic_epoch)
toc_total = time.time()
print('time elapsed:',toc_total-tic_total)
```

Results:

```
time per epoch: 1.2558062076568604
time per epoch: 0.2627861499786377
time per epoch: 0.25072169303894043
time per epoch: 0.250835657119751
time per epoch: 0.2861459255218506
time per epoch: 0.26630401611328125
time per epoch: 0.24439024925231934
time per epoch: 0.23915791511535645
time per epoch: 0.25443601608276367
time per epoch: 0.2899332046508789
time elapsed: 4.2830810546875
```

Pytorch version

```
import numpy as np
import torch.utils
import torch.utils.data
from torch import nn
import time

dims = 600
DATA_SIZE = 10000
batchsz = 100
epochs = 10
lr = 1e-3
inputs = np.random.random([DATA_SIZE, dims]).astype(np.float32)
targets = np.random.random([DATA_SIZE, dims]).astype(np.float32)
tic_total = time.time()
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(dims, dims),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(dims, dims),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(dims, dims),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(dims, dims),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(dims, dims),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(dims, dims)
).cuda()

train_x = torch.tensor(inputs).cuda()
train_y = torch.tensor(targets).cuda()

train_db = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(train_x, train_y)
train_db = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_db, batch_size=batchsz, shuffle=True)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
model.train()
for epoch in range(epochs):
    tic_epoch = time.time()
    for step, data in enumerate(train_db):
        loss = (model(data[0]) - data[1]).square().mean()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    toc_epoch = time.time()
    print('time per epoch:', toc_epoch - tic_epoch)
toc_total = time.time()
print('time elapsed:', toc_total - tic_total)
```

Results:

```
time per epoch: 1.1492640972137451
time per epoch: 0.4739706516265869
time per epoch: 0.4949944019317627
time per epoch: 0.48531651496887207
time per epoch: 0.4747319221496582
time per epoch: 0.4962129592895508
time per epoch: 0.6802644729614258
time per epoch: 0.5593955516815186
time per epoch: 0.4838066101074219
time per epoch: 0.4937736988067627
time elapsed: 8.071050882339478
```

Comment: Tensorflow 2 introduced `Better performance with tf.function`. In TensorFlow 2, eager execution is turned on by default. You can use tf.function to make graphs out of your programs. It is a transformation tool that creates Python-independent dataflow graphs out of your Python code. This will help you create performant and portable models, and it is required to use SavedModel. For more details on Tensorflow 2 performance can find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function).Thanks!